# Strange iframe scrolling behaviour in Safari desktop

Tags: html, css, iframe, safari

I couldn't find any relevant information about this issue.

If the parent container has a fixed height and overflow: scroll, then the inner iframe is not scrolling properly. It could be scrolled only to the bottom or only to the top. But not at the same time.

Though it works fine if I remove overflow: scroll; from the #outer container.

Please take a look at the attached code snippet and run it in Safari.

Currently, I'm using Safari Version 9.0.3, OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

UPD:
I found out that this bug can be reproduced only with Apple input devise, Magic Mouse or touchpad.
Check out the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IpjAbWgbuc

I couldn't reproduce the bug in the snippet so here's the actual html page:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/plio/other/iframe_scroll_safari_issue.html

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#outer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#inner1, #inner2 {
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#scrollable1, #scrollable2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#scrollable1 > *, #scrollable2 > * {
  border: 3px dashed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner1">
        <div id="scrollable1">
          <img src="http://static.fjcdn.com/pictures/Long_3c2320_670942.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="inner2">
        <iframe id="scrollable2" src="https://plio.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/KwKXz5RefrE5hjWJ2/standards-files/HLiWGZdNL5hifyRhJ/YCWzyS3XX2Wkko6tv-demo.docx.html"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work normally on my safari. Using 9.1 here.

Comment: @adamk22 did you use a regular mouse or Apple Magic Mouse/Trackpad?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your iframes this js event: `onmousewheel='event.preventDefault();'`.
If this doesn't work, tell me.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. [https://i.gyazo.com/c5925594b7d58d1a1abf51fdd13c6be4.gif](https://i.gyazo.com/c5925594b7d58d1a1abf51fdd13c6be4.gif)

Comment: Try changing `onmousewheel` with `onscroll`

Comment: Oops! Add `onscroll='event.stopPropagation()'` instead. Sorry!

Comment: It didn't help me as well. Turns out that it could be a problem with Magic Mouse or other original Apple input devise.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting the body within the iFrame to `height: 100%;`

Comment: does not work for me.